# How does hostname -i work?

Tags: networking, dns, ip-address, hostname

I know that I can get the external IP address of my machine / a Docker container from within by running:

```
$ hostname -i
```

Now I would like to implement a similar mechanism by myself, but for this I would need to know how `hostname -i` works internally. Unfortunately, this is very hard to google for, since you can not search for `-i` (or, at least, I wasn't able to figure out how).

So, my question is, how does this command figure out the external IP address? The only thing I can imagine is running a DNS lookup using the machine's hostname. Is there any more to it?